# php unlink() not found

Tags: php, unlink

When I call `unlink` like so:
`unlink($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);`

I get the following error message:
`unlink(): No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/file.php on line 18, referer: http://localhost/file.php`

I know I'm  not exactly proficient in the language, but I checked the manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php and I seem to be using it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `$_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']` does not exist. Try to print it to check is it correct path.

Anyway, You don't need delete tmp files, they will be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to unlink an uploaded file? PHP will do it for you when the script handling the upload exits. This is default behavior - unless you take explicit steps to preserve the file, or PHP crashes hard, the uploaded files will ALWAYS be cleaned up for you.

Of course, if you're doing a `move_uploaded_file()` or similar before you do the unlink, then the temporary file will no longer be there, which is why you're getting this error.